# Is there a way to rename an existing Rails Engine easily?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rails-engines

There is a plugin for renaming an existing Rails app - https://github.com/get/Rename

But is there some solution to easily and fully rename an existing Rails Engine?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?  What are you referring to when you say "Rails Engine"?

Comment: @6ftDan Rails::Engine allows you to wrap a specific Rails application or subset of functionality and share it with other applications or within a larger packaged application. Every Rails::Application is just an engine, which allows for simple feature and application sharing.